# SEVERE: Error processing TLD files for context path ..java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, jakarta-ee, tomcat6

I am getting the following exception when starting tomcat 6 in eclipse :

```
May 14, 2014 12:55:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig lifecycleEvent
SEVERE: Error processing TLD files for context path 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
    at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.getJarPaths(TldConfig.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.execute(TldConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.lifecycleEvent(TldConfig.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:583)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
May 14, 2014 12:55:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig lifecycleEvent
**SEVERE: Error processing TLD files for context path /MYAPP**
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
    at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.getJarPaths(TldConfig.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.execute(TldConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.lifecycleEvent(TldConfig.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:583)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
May 14, 2014 12:55:17 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
```

I looked at some answers online but could not find any specific reason for this exception.
Can someone please explain why this exception is coming ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Try steps below:

1. setup the new tomcat server from local workspace.
2. After setting up the server, change the ports as follows:

   a. double click on the tomcat server in server panel

   b. It will open an configuration panel.

   c. change the ports. save changes.

   d. right click on the server and start the server.

Hope this my resolve. If not, please post other solution/workaround